# Bower - ENOGIT git is not installed or not in the PATH using Symfony Process

Tags: node.js, git, symfony, bower

We are currently running into an issue where runnning `bower update --allow-root` via Symfony's Process component which results in an error or;

`bower jquery#* <3.0 * * * * * * * * ENOGIT git is not installed or not in the PATH`

Running `git` or `bower` via the component retrieves expected response.

It seems as if bower/node cant find the git path. Running the follwoing via Symphony Process

`echo $PATH`

results in

`/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`

inside `/usr/bin` is;

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root          35 Feb 21 09:06 bower -> ../lib/node_modules/bower/bin/bower
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root          22 Jan 23 11:49 node -> /etc/alternatives/node
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root          25163808 Jan  6 00:12 nodejs
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root          38 Jan  6 00:11 npm -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root          1862800 Mar 23  2016 git
```

Running `which git` via Symfony Process returns `/usr/bin/git`

Running `which bower` via Symfony Process returns `/usr/bin/bower`

Running `which node` via Symfony Process returns `/usr/bin/node`

Stack Trace:

```
Error: git is not installed or not in the PATH
    at createError (/usr/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/util/createError.js:4:15)
    at GitHubResolver.GitResolver (/usr/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/core/resolvers/GitResolver.js:45:15)
    at GitHubResolver.GitRemoteResolver (/usr/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/core/resolvers/GitRemoteResolver.js:10:17)
    at new GitHubResolver (/usr/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/core/resolvers/GitHubResolver.js:13:23)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/core/resolverFactory.js:18:16
From previous event:
    at PackageRepository.fetch (/usr/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/core/PackageRepository.js:46:6)
    at Manager._fetch (/usr/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/core/Manager.js:323:51)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Manager.resolve (/usr/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/core/Manager.js:116:23)
    at Project._bootstrap (/usr/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/core/Project.js:559:6)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/core/Project.js:193:21

Console trace:
Error
    at StandardRenderer.error (/usr/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/renderers/StandardRenderer.js:81:37)
    at Logger.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/bin/bower.js:110:26)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Logger.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Logger.emit (/usr/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/bower-logger/lib/Logger.js:29:39)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/commands/index.js:48:20
    at _rejected (/usr/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:844:24)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:870:30
    at Promise.when (/usr/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:1122:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:788:41)
```

Server:

```
NGINX 
1 GB  
30 GB Disk 
Ubuntu 16.04.1 x64
Linux 4.4.0-62-generic x64
```

has anyone else ran into this problem or could suggest more tests to debug.

regards

***EDIT***

Ive debugged it back to `/usr/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/util/createError.js`

```
var which = require('which');
var hasGit;

// Check if git is installed
try {
    which.sync('git');
    hasGit = true;
} catch (ex) {
    hasGit = false;
}
```

***EDIT 2***

tracked it down to a node module `which`;

https://github.com/npm/node-which/blob/master/which.js#L21

which the line `process.env.PATH` is returning `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin; bower update
```

`process.env.PATH` was returning `undefined` from the `which` node module;

https://github.com/npm/node-which/blob/master/which.js#L21

Adding the `PATH` prefix to the command fixed this issue.

Being more specific to my issue, Symfony's Process class takes a third parameter for environment variables;

```
$process = new Process( 'php composer.phar update', $path, [ 'PATH' => '/usr/bin', 'HOME' => '/home/forge' ] );
```